# Combine duplicates and create one comprehensive list

Tags: vba, sql-server-2012, excel-2010

I was wondering what the easiest way would be to get the data I needed.

I am not sure if it is even possible to add columns like that or not. If so I am not sure where the easiest place to accomplish this would be.

Excel Formula, SQL, or VBA code?

I have a huge list of names and what I want to do is take all of the data for a name and get all the unique data from the table then put it in a list basically.

Any help would be appreciated.

**DATA**

```
  Name    | FirstID | SecondID | ThirdID | FourthID | FifthID |
-------------------------------------------------------------
Joe Smith | AB.5    | AC.1     | AH.9    | ZZ.4     | BB.9    |
Joe Smith | DD.7    | AC.1     | AD.3    | XD.5     | BB.9    |
Joe Smith | RV.4    | AC.1     | AD.3    | ZZ.4     | BB.9    |
Joe Smith | AB.5    | AC.1     | AD.3    | ZZ.4     | BB.9    |
```

**Desired Results**

```
  Name    
-------------------------------------------------------------
Joe Smith | AB.5 | AC.1 | AH.9 | ZZ.4 | BB.9 | DD.7 | AD.3 | XD.5 | RV.4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be a fairly easy task, so Ill let you know what youd need to do to get this results

1) Learn to open and go through a recordset using vba. Plenty of articles on it and its super easy.

2) Your SQL for this would be SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Name ='thename'

3) Learn how to store values in an array, or a new tables

4) learn how to check your array or table for preexisting values from the current step in your recordset, and if not there add it(the value in the current spot in the recordset that is).

Happy coding and good luck! Come back when you have tried something and have code to show

Comment: Or you can use a dictionary instead of an array in order to store unique keys. Long story short, as Doug stated, you should show a sign of effort in order to get your code working.